# How to display the Apache Server Status module in realtime?

Tags: apache-2.2

For example on the top part of this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLcL61iLNT0

He is running the server status is realtime, how can you do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the watch command to run apache2ctl status repeatedly eg:

```
watch apache2ctl status
```

Comment: How did this guy do it then?

Comment: @James , what do you mean? The `watch` command will run `apache2ctl status` every N seconds. `apache2ctl status` will show the output of mod_status status as shown in the video. Read the watch(1) manpage, and see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_status.html#autoupdate & http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/apachectl.html

Comment: My appologies, I have just configered the module for apache2 and works flawlessly.

Answer (score 6):

Once you enable server status as per http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html just add `?refresh=1` to the end of your server-status URL.

I believe it is as close to real-time as you're going to get.

Comment: How did this guy do it then?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is with ?refresh=1 - if you look at the video, it updates once a second.

Comment: The video shows a text browser in use, and none of the text browsers I've tried support auto-refresh, so the solution likely will require other methods to refresh the page.

Comment: It works just fine with elinks http://elinks.or.cz/ on CentOS/RHEL 5.x

Comment: Ahh, I didn't try elinks, only links and lynx.

Comment: elinks === links - CentOS 5.6 is using version 0.11.1, release 6.el5_4.1

Comment: This works for me: `links -html-auto-refresh 1 "http://hosta.example.gov/server-status?refresh=1"`

Answer (score 2):

Probably something like:

```
$ watch -n 1 links -dump http://localhost/server-status
```

Answer (score 1):

lynx http://localhost/server-status

As you can see from the video, that's a view of the scoreboard. Doing some quick googling showed me the above link from this one:

http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/3/26/enabling-and-using-apache-s-mod_status-on-debian